# Determine an event's presence and unique ID using start and end flags in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that has start and end flags for unique events coded as "start" and "end" in a factor. Indices including and in between "start" and "end" are counted as part of the event. Thus, I'd like to make `eventFlag` which is a logical indicating whether an event is taking place and `eventIndex` which gives the an increasing number to each event.

```
# what I have
eventPoints <- factor(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"start",NA,NA,NA,NA,
    "end",NA,NA,"start",NA,"end",NA,NA,"start","end",NA))
# what I want
eventFlag <-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,
    TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,
    TRUE,FALSE)
eventIndex <-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,3,3,0)

data.frame(eventPoints,eventFlag,eventIndex)
```

The events are in strict increasing order if that helps or simplifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a sequence index based on the corresponding occurrence of 'start', 'end' in the 'eventPoints'

```
s1 <- with(df1, unlist(Map(seq, which(eventPoints == "start"), 
                        which(eventPoints == "end"))))
df1$eventFlag <- FALSE
df1$eventFlag[s1] <- TRUE
```

and the 'eventIndex' can be created with run-length-encoding (`rle`)

```
df1$eventIndex <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df1$eventFlag), 
                   values[values] <- seq_along(values[values])))

df1
#   eventPoints eventFlag eventIndex
#1         <NA>     FALSE          0
#2         <NA>     FALSE          0
#3         <NA>     FALSE          0
#4         <NA>     FALSE          0
#5        start      TRUE          1
#6         <NA>      TRUE          1
#7         <NA>      TRUE          1
#8         <NA>      TRUE          1
#9         <NA>      TRUE          1
#10         end      TRUE          1
#11        <NA>     FALSE          0
#12        <NA>     FALSE          0
#13       start      TRUE          2
#14        <NA>      TRUE          2
#15         end      TRUE          2
#16        <NA>     FALSE          0
#17        <NA>     FALSE          0
#18       start      TRUE          3
#19         end      TRUE          3
#20        <NA>     FALSE          0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(eventPoints)
```

Comment: I knew `rle` was going to be involved but wouldn't have gotten there easily. Thanks.